# How to seed values in a SQL database using IdentityUser as a foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

## Explanation:

I use a static class called Seeds that seed my database with data samples from Program.cs:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                // Get services
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                // Create/Seed the database
                Seeds.SeedDatabase(services);

                // Create the roles for the application
                var serviceProvider = services.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();
                var configuration = services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                Seeds.CreateRoles(serviceProvider, configuration).Wait();
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Here is Seeds:

```
public class Seeds
    {
public static void SeedDatabase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Seed DB
            using (var _db = new AppDbContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>>()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n Looking for a database... \n");

                // Look for a database
                if (!_db.Database.EnsureCreated())
                {
                    // Debug message
                    string message = "\n There is already a database. \n";
                    Console.WriteLine(message);

                    // DB has been seeded before
                }
                else
                {
                    // Debug message
                    string message = "\n A new database has been created. \n";
                    Console.WriteLine(message);

                     _db.FlightSettings.Add(
                        new FlightSetting(
                            ...Variables...
                            ),
                     );

                    ...Here other values are seeded as FlightSettings...

                    // Save the data samples
                    _db.SaveChanges();

                    // DB has been seeded now
                }
            }
        }

    }

public static async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

        {
            //adding customs roles
            var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();

            // Roles in the project
            string[] roleNames = { "Pilot", "Office" };

            IdentityResult roleResult;

            foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
            {
                // creating the roles and seeding them to the database
                var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);

                if (!roleExist)
                {
                    roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                }
            }

            // create custom users
            var officeUser = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = "paulita",
                Email = "paulita@",
                Password = "paulita"
            };

            var pilots = new AppUser[] {
                new AppUser
                {
                    Name = "pablito",
                    IdentityDocument = 80421514,
                    EmployeeNumber = 52641958,
                    UserName = "pcastellanos",
                    Email = "pablito@",
                    Password = "pablito",
                    BornDate = new DateTime(1990, 6, 20)
                },
                new AppUser
                {
                    Name = "pedrito",
                    IdentityDocument = 1098808192,
                    EmployeeNumber = 62549214,
                    UserName = "privero",
                    Email = "pedrito@",
                    Password = "pedrito",
                    BornDate = new DateTime(1992, 8, 10)
                }
            };

            foreach (var pilot in pilots)
            {
                await UserManager.CreateAsync(pilot, pilot.Password);
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(pilot, "Pilot");
            }

            await UserManager.CreateAsync(officeUser, officeUser.Password);
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(officeUser, "Office");

            using (var _db = new AppDbContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>>()))
            {
                var myPilots = await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Pilot");
                AppUser myUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("pcastellanos");
                var flightSettings = await _db.FlightSettings.ToListAsync();

                await _db.PilotTests.AddAsync(
                    new PilotTest
                    {
                        Pilot = myUser,
                        SimulationSetting = flightSettings[0]
                    }
                );

                // Save the data samples
                _db.SaveChanges();
```

## Problem

As you can see in this line:

```
var myPilots = await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Pilot");
```

I request to the database all users in the role "Pilot". I'm gettting an error when creating a PilotTest because in PilotTest instead of just referencing the respective AppUser, it also tries to create the AppUser again, and as the user already exists, VisualStudio tells me that there is already an entry in the database with that Primay Key.

Each PiloTest should reference one Pilot. Here is PilotTest table in the DB:
[image: PilotTestTableDB]

I tried to add just one Pilot here:

```
AppUser myUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("pcastellanos");
```

But the same happens.

Here are both classess:

```
public class PilotTest
    {
        // Unique ID
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // The pilot responsible for this test
        public AppUser Pilot { get; set; }

        // FlightSetting of the simulation
        public FlightSetting SimulationSetting { get; set; }

        ...Other variables...
    }

public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        // Custom variables on users
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IdentityDocument { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime BornDate { get; set; }

        // For debugging purposes 
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

My theory is that I'm doing something wrong, but since a few days ago I just cannot find any solution.

Comment: Check whether there is any user in `AspNetUsers` in database by `await UserManager.CreateAsync(pilot, pilot.Password);`. Your method `Seeds.CreateRoles(serviceProvider, configuration).Wait();` is not corresponding to `public static async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` method defination.

Answer (score 0):

For your current defination password `paulita`, it is invalid according to default password rule. You could change the code like below, check the `result` you will find the error.

```
foreach (var pilot in pilots)
{
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(pilot, pilot.Password);
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(pilot, "Pilot");
}
```

If you prefer for this password, you need to configure the `IdentityOptions` like

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(options => {
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
})
```

Here is my current `Seeds`

```
public class Seeds
{
    public static void SeedDatabase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Seed DB
        using (var _db = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestMVC2_1Context>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Looking for a database... \n");

            // Look for a database
            if (!_db.Database.EnsureCreated())
            {
                // Debug message
                string message = "\n There is already a database. \n";
                Console.WriteLine(message);

                // DB has been seeded before
            }
            else
            {
                // Debug message
                string message = "\n A new database has been created. \n";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                // Save the data samples
                _db.SaveChanges();

                // DB has been seeded now
            }
        }
    }
    public static async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

    {
        //adding customs roles
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();

        // Roles in the project
        string[] roleNames = { "Pilot", "Office" };

        IdentityResult roleResult;

        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            // creating the roles and seeding them to the database
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);

            if (!roleExist)
            {
                roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }

        // create custom users
        var officeUser = new AppUser
        {
            UserName = "paulita",
            Email = "paulita@",
            Password = "paulita"
        };

        var pilots = new AppUser[] {
            new AppUser
            {
                Name = "pablito",
                IdentityDocument = 80421514,
                EmployeeNumber = 52641958,
                UserName = "pcastellanos",
                Email = "pablito@",
                Password = "pablito",
                BornDate = new DateTime(1990, 6, 20)
            },
            new AppUser
            {
                Name = "pedrito",
                IdentityDocument = 1098808192,
                EmployeeNumber = 62549214,
                UserName = "privero",
                Email = "pedrito@",
                Password = "pedrito",
                BornDate = new DateTime(1992, 8, 10)
            }
        };

        foreach (var pilot in pilots)
        {
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(pilot, pilot.Password);
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(pilot, "Pilot");
        }

        await UserManager.CreateAsync(officeUser, officeUser.Password);
        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(officeUser, "Office");

        using (var _db = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestMVC2_1Context>())
        {
            var myPilots = await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Pilot");
            AppUser myUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("pcastellanos");

            await _db.PilotTests.AddAsync(
                new PilotTest
                {
                    Pilot = myUser,
                }
            );

            // Save the data samples
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

}
```